# translating gsub command from R into Python

Tags: python, r, regex

I want to split this mystring="0G15^GAC0T60T4^AA0C0" and get the following output with python:

```
['0','G','15','^GAC','T','60','T','4','^AA','C']
```

It could be done with this command in R:

```
mystring <- "0G15^GAC0T60T4^AA0C0"
gsub("([\\^]*[ACGT]+)[0]*", " \\1 ", mystring)
```

how can I translate the R script into python?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can reuse your existing regular expression using Pythons [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) module

```
import re

mystring = "0G15^GAC0T60T4^AA0C0"
l = re.sub("([\\^]*[ACGT]+)[0]*", " \\1 ", mystring).split()
```

`l` is then

```
['0', 'G', '15', '^GAC', 'T', '60', 'T', '4', '^AA', 'C']
```

Comment: Nice regex dude!... great answer! it's a plus one

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
mystring="0G15^GAC0T60T4^AA0C0" 
import re
new_data = re.findall('(?<!\^[GAC])\d+|(?<!\^)\w|\^[a-zA-Z]+', mystring)
final_data = [a for i, a in enumerate(new_data) if a != '0' or not new_data[i-1].startswith("^")][:-1]
```

Output:

```
['0', 'G', '15', '^GAC', 'T', '60', 'T', '4', '^AA', 'C']
```

Comment: the ouput is not the same